# Jquery multidimensional array autocomplete

Tags: jquery, forms, multidimensional-array, autocomplete

i'm trying to use Jquery autocomplete function getting data from a multidimensional array (see the code below), i want that user write on the form field called "descrizione" getting results from the array field "prodotto" and automatically when he confirm the product chosen the other fields are set.
Anyone can help me to understand what is wrong on the code?
Thanks for your kind cooperation!

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableDescrizioni = [
{ prodotto: "test test", codice_prodotto: "product_code001", prezzo: "122,22", iva: "22" },
{ prodotto: "nome_prodotto1", codice_prodotto: "cod_produttore1", prezzo: "22,22", iva: "22" }

    ];

    $("#descrizione").autocomplete({
        source: $availableDescrizioni,

        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#descrizione").val(ui.item.prodotto);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#descrizione").val(ui.item.prodotto);
            $("#cod_prodotto").val(ui.item.codice_prodotto);
            $("#prezzo_unitario").val(ui.item.prezzo);
            return false;
        }
    });



  });
</script>


<input type="text" id="cod_prodotto" name="cod_prodotto" class="colonna col_codprodotto"/>
<input type="text" name="quantita" class="colonna col_quantita"/>
<input type="text" id="descrizione" name="descrizione" class="colonna col_descrizione"/> 
<input type="text" id="prezzo_unitario" name="prezzo_unitario" class="colonna col_prezzo"/> 
<input type="text" name="cod_iva" class="colonna col_prezzo"/>
```

Comment: I'm including: 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems within your code :

- your `availableDescrizioni` variable is not in a valid format to be the source of the autocomplete widget. If you want to use an Objects array, each object must contains at least a `value` property which is used by the widget to filter results. ([see the doc for more details](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source))
- you have an extra `$` sign on this line : `source: $availableDescrizioni,`

Have a look in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SRYy/1/) to see it in action

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help! i tried many times but i didn't know that value property was mandatory.